# apply a list of functions to a value one after another

Tags: haskell

Is there a built in function to apply a list of functions to a value one after another? I am currently using this, but it seems quite inelegant to me.

```
-- applyFunctions [(*2), (+3), (*4)] 1 == ((1 * 2) + 3 ) * 4
applyFunctions :: [(a -> a)] -> a -> a
applyFunctions [] x = x
applyFunctions [f] x = f x
applyFunctions (f:fs) x = applyFunctions fs (f x)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `foldl (flip ($))`

```
foldl (flip ($)) 1 [(*2), (*3), (*4)] --yields 24
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a fold:

```
import Data.List
applyFunctions = flip $ foldl' (flip ($))
```

or you could be more explicit:

```
applyFunctions l e = foldl' (|>) e l
  where a |> f = f a
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a built in function but the application is trivial.

```
applyFunctions :: [(a -> a)] -> a -> a
applyFunctions [] v = v
applyFunctions (f:fs) v = applyFunctions fs $ f v
```

Comment: Oh, my middle case (`applyFunctions [f] x = f x`) is unnecessary. Thanks. :) But I was hoping something cool/monadic/whatever. ;)

Comment: @Dobi: Fold works, I just couldn't figure out if it was fold, map, reduce, or something else so posted this.

Comment: @Guvante Shouldn't that be `applyFunctions (f:fs) v = applyFunctions fs $ f v`?  There needs to be parens around the pattern `f:fs` and you don't need parens around the `v` in `f v`.